# Can i use React lazy and React Transition Group together?

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group, react-lazy-load

I have a question. Can I use React lazy with React Transition group? (for example load component with lazy and after loaded add animation)?

I would try do it in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-butterfly-58vp0s?file=/src/App.tsx